# Markov chain probability with formula 1-p-q

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Consider $(\theta^{(n)}: n\ge 0)$, a markov chain in S={0, 1} with initial distribution $\pi^{(0)}=(\pi^{(0)}(0), \pi^{(0)}(1))$ and transition matrix P given by $P=\begin{pmatrix}1-p&p\\q&1-q\end{pmatrix}$. Using the relation $P(\theta^{(n)}=0)=\sum_{j\in S}P(\theta^{(n)}=0, \theta^{(n-1)}=j)$ for $n\ge 1$ and the Markovian property of the chain,

$$\begin{split}P(\theta^{(n)}=0) &= (1-p)P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0)+qP(\theta^{(n-1)}=1)\\
 &= (1-p-q)^n \pi^{(0)}(0) + q\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-p-q)^k\end{split}$$

Been thinking about how they got the second step for a few days, but still stumped. Why's there $1-p-q$

I thought about

- going from the first expression to the second expression, in which case I could figure no substitution to connect the two
- how the second equation may make sense standalone, which I still had no success due to not knowing why there is 1-p-q

I found a formula, but it didn't help much: $P(\theta^{(n)}=y)=\sum_{x\in S}P^n(x, y)\pi^{(0)}(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess they are proving by induction that

$$
\begin{split}P(\theta^{(n)}=0) = (1-p-q)^n \pi^{(0)}(0) + q\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-p-q)^k\end{split}.
$$

In the second step they use the inductive assumption, namely the above formula for $n-1$. And it simplifies to the formula for $n$ and the proof is done. Notice that $P(\theta^{(n-1)}=1) = 1 - P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0)$.

$$P(\theta^{(n)}=0)
= (1-p)P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0)+qP(\theta^{(n-1)}=1) \\
= (1-p)P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0)+q\left(1-P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0)\right) \\
= (1-p-q)P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0) + q \\
= (1-p-q) \left(  (1-p-q)^{n-1} \pi^{(0)}(0) + q\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(1-p-q)^k \right) + q\\
= (1-p-q)^{n} \pi^{(0)}(0) + \left(q\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(1-p-q)^{k+1}\right) + q \\
= (1-p-q)^{n} \pi^{(0)}(0) + q\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-p-q)^{k}\right) \\
= (1-p-q)^{n} \pi^{(0)}(0) + q\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-p-q)^{k}. 
$$

Comment: That’s new to me, I didn’t know induction can be used like that!

Comment: @Jellyfish I think the key step is writing $P(\theta^{(n-1)}=1) = 1 - P(\theta^{(n-1)}=0)$. Then you have what's on the third line of my last chain of equations, i.e. at each step $P(\theta=0)$ gets multiplied by $(1-p-q)$ and $q$ gets added. That's how you can notice the formula in the first place. But they are sure leaving out a lot of steps.